# My template page automatically zooms on mobile devices

Tags: android, jquery, html, mobile

For some reason, whenever I open one of my pages on my mobile template using an actual mobile device, it automatically zooms in on the page. Is there any way to make sure the page starts at 100%?

Here's my code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      li{
        line-height:3em;
      }
      ad{
        padding: 0 0 0 4em;
      }
      n{
        margin:10;
      }
      p {
        font-size: 130%;
      }
      a:link { color: white; text-decoration: none}
      mm {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin:0;
        list-style-type: none;
      }
      m {
        width: 6em;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        margin:10px;
        background-color: #243d77;
        padding: 0.9em 0.6em;
      }
    </style>
    <title>[Content]</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/[Content].css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/pngFix/jquery.pngFix.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
      shuffle = function(o){ //v1.0
        for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
        return o;
      };

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).pngFix(); 
      }); 
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="/index.htm">
            <img alt="" width="189" height="69" src="[Content]" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="loginlink">
          <a href="client-login.htm">
            Client Access Click Here
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="subheader">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <div style="clear: left;"></div>
        <div id="wrapper1">
          <div style="text-align: center;">
          </div>
          <div id="wrapper2">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
            </div>
            <div id="maincol">
              <div style="text-align: center;">
              </div>
              <div id="leftcol">
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                  <mm>
                    <li>
                      <m>
                        <n>
                          <a href="#">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Home &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                          </a>
                        </n>
                      </m>
                    </li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li>
                      <m>
                        <n>
                          <a href="#">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; What We Do &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                          </a>
                        </n>
                      </m>
                    </li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li>
                      <m>
                        <n>
                          <a href="#">
                            &nbsp; &nbsp; Why Work With Us&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                          </a>
                        </n>
                      </m>
                    </li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li>
                      <m>
                        <n>
                          <a href="#">
                            &nbsp;How We Provide Value &nbsp;
                          </a>
                        </n>
                      </m>
                    </li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li>
                      <m>
                        <n>
                          <a href="#">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp; Who We Work With &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                          </a>
                        </n>
                      </m>
                    </li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li>
                      <m>
                        <n>
                          <a href="#">
                            Results We've Achieved&nbsp;
                          </a>
                        </n>
                      </m>
                    </li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li>
                      <m>
                        <n>
                          <a href="#">
                            &nbsp; &nbsp; Where We Service &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
                          </a>
                        </n>
                      </m>
                    </li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li>
                      <m>
                        <n>
                          <a href="#">
                            &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; [Content] &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                          </a>
                        </n>
                      </m>
                    </li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li>
                      <m>
                        <n>
                          <a href="#">
                            &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; Get In Touch &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                          </a>
                        </n>
                      </m>
                    </li>
                  </mm>
                </div>
                <mm>
                </mm>
              </div>
            </div>
            {tag_pagecontent}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      <div id="footer">
        <p>&copy; 2014 [Content]</p>
        <p>
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/sitemap.htm">Site Map</a></li>
          <li><a href="/disclaimer.htm">Disclaimer</a></li>
          <li><a href="/privacy.htm">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try adding this ? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `&nbsp;`s to do your spacing, you should be using CSS for that.

Answer (score 1):

That behavior is device-dependant, modern Android 4.x phones have an option called "*Open pages in overview*", enabled by default, which cause web pages page to be shown entirely (without zoom).

Usually, forcing a 100% zoom level and disabling the user's ability to zoom on the phone is a common practice for properly displaying (**correctly designed**) mobile sites. This is achieved with the viewport meta tag shown below.

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```

The `initial-scale=1.0` value means that the zoom is set to 100% and, `user-scalable=0` means that user-zooming is disabled. You could play around with the `initial-scale` value, but results could vary from one platform to the other.

Try setting this meta tag to see if it works and forces an initiall zoom of 50%:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1' name='viewport' />
```

Again, this is a non-conventional use of the tag, as you are trying to force a zoom-out instead of a zoom-in, but try it and tell if it works...